# How to change Culture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, calendar, culture

Sorry my very poor english ...

I'm using asp.net control toolkit to do a calendar on asp.net mvc, and it works fine! But it is in english format date. How can i change to pt-BR culture? I read lot of sites, but i couldn't implement on my project.

Anyone could put a link to show me a valid implementation about culture?

And why putting: `<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt"/>` in webconfig file between system.web tags doesn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easy option would be to change you browsers language; as it should then pick up this as the native culture to use (in internet explorer this is: tools > internet options > below appearance there is language)

Alternatively look at doing:

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture
```

To force your application to return in this culture.

Comment: found a page on the msdn, but I am guessing you already may have seen it?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Comment: I actually found changing the browser's language to be easiest when testing. Thanks for the tip.